# A new tab appears and dissapears in Chrome as soon as I start working on the computer

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

Recently I noticed that when using Chrome with some tabs open (Facebook on one of them), sometimes when I come back to the computer, I see a new tab with Facebook page on it, but it immediately disappears.

It almost never opens when I work in front of the computer - only when I'm returning in front of the computer. It's very strange and very annoy not to know what causes this tab to open. It's never something else - always Facebook.

When I click "Reopen close tab" afterwards, it always opens Facebook. I have only 3 extensions installed: Quick and Clean, You Tube downloader and Quick Note.

Does someone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Maybe you have a few bugs or ghosts in your machine?

Comment: BTW, is this for Windows or Linux/UNIX?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which operating system, but try these -

1. Disable your Chrome extensions here - **chrome://extensions/**  (use copy-and-paste, as internal links aren't clickable).  If the problem goes away, re-enable them one by one to isolate which one is causing your issue.  Also doesn't help to remove any long-dead extensions you no longer use.
2. Go to the Chrome internal URL for apps and see if there are any apps related to Facebook that are installed - **chrome://apps/**  Once again, if the problem disappears, re-enable each app to isolate the cause.  And again, remove apps you never use.
3. Right-click Chrome task bar icon (or systray icon, if you use that) and open the Chrome Task Manager - if you're quick when you come back to your, this *might* hint at what tabs are flickering when you come back to your PC.
4. Is the reopen-last-closed-tab URL only **www.facebook.com** or does it have something that may indicate why it was opened?  Remember reopening closed tabs also shows the back-history of the tab, so if it's jumping back to the simple URL, you might need to go back to see the launched URL.

PS: When you say *"come back to the computer"* - are you using a screen saver?  Maybe change the settings to a very short timeout and see if that still causes the issue (maybe Facebook chat presence is trying to update from *Available* to *Idle/Away*, etc?).